How does polkadot js calculate the weight and percentage usage for a block?
On the block page in polkadotjs you can see the weight consumed by a block, and the percentage of the maximum weight.
How is this calculated/displayed on polkadotjs? Is there an RPC to get this information for a particular block?
Does this include hook weight usage? A quick look at the code suggests not? Is there a way to get this information?

It's stored in the System pallet storage:

